# Pipeline Processor Calculation

Tags: cpu, clock, cycle, frequency, pipeline

My assignment deals with calculations of pipelined CPU and single cycle CPU clock rates.

The following data is given, about the time each operation takes to execute:

```
IF:400 PS
ID:100 PS
EX:350 PS 
MEM:700 PS
WB:100 PS

A. What is the clock frequency if the CPU works as a single cycle? How long does it take to execute a single operation?
B. What is the clock frequency if the CPU works as a Pipelines CPU? How long does it take to execute a single operation?
```

I know that for A a single operation takes 1650 ps  to execute because in a single cycle CPU we have to perform every stage to execute a single operation. What I don't understand is why is the frequency 0.606?

For B, I know that to execute we have 700 Ps, because a pipelined CPU takes to longest stage as the CPU as the time. What I don't know, is what is the answer to the frequency question?

Any help is blessed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well frequency is the reciprocal of time, so:

```
1 / 1650 ps = 606 MHz = 0.606 GHz
```

and

```
1 / 700 ps = 1429 MHz = 1.429 GHz
```

Note that the prefix `p` stands for `pico`, which is a multiplier of 10<sup>-12</sup>. So one picosecond (`ps`) is equal to 10<sup>-12</sup> = 0.000000000001 seconds.